# How to check file location in window mobile 6 professional vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i face check txt file location problem in window mobile 6 professional.

code testing for window form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "c:\Users\Chee Kang\Desktop\New folder (2)\testFile.txt"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("File already Exist")


    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
End Sub
```

coding above show me the correct answer :File already Exist (i pasted the file there before i start my program)

but when i apply the same thing in window mobile 6 professional, it give me the wrong answer "File Does Not Exist" although i pasted the file there before i start my program.

i try to figure out the reason, but so far i can't get any correct reason.

Kindly advise.
thanks

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/3e73293d-eda5-43b0-8018-a19144643922/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile does not use drive letters.
Your path does not exist.

Comment: what means by "Windows Mobile does not use drive letters" ?

and how can i solved this if i need to check a file location? 

i doing a project, the flow like :
when i send a file to window mobile 6 professional at a specific location, and once the file is detect, it will automatically trigger another button.

can you provide me a alternative way to solve it?
thanks a lot

Comment: I mean exactly what I said.  Windows Mobile doesn't have drives.  Instead, it uses paths starting with `\​`.

Comment: how can i solved this if i need to check a file in a window mobile location? 

i am doing a project, the flow like :
when i send a file to window mobile 6 professional at a specific location, and once the file is detect at that location, it will automatically trigger another button.

as we know we can check the file location at laptop easily (just click the properties, and check the location), but how we can check the location of file received in window mobile 6 professional? 
can you provide me a alternative way or idea to solve it?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When we work with files on WinMo 6, we store and retrieve all files in directories relative to the installed application so that we don't have to worry about the WinMo directory structure.

To get the path to the installed app, you can use code similar to the following:

```
''' <summary>
''' Because the Windows Mobile doesn't have a current directory, this 
''' method provides a way to get to the directory for this assembly.
''' </summary>
Public ReadOnly Property GetBaseDirectory() As String
    Get
        Dim sName As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase

        sName = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sName)
        '
        ' Support for unit testing on the desktop. CodeBase returns a path with "file:\" at the start
        ' under Windows, but not under Windows CE. The code that uses this property expects
        ' the path without the file:\ at the start.
        '
        If Environment.OSVersion.Platform <> PlatformID.WinCE Then
            If sName.StartsWith("file:\") Then
                sName = sName.Remove(0, 6)
            End If
        End If
        Return sName
    End Get
End Property
```

Note that this code also supports unit testing on non-CE platforms. Once you get the base directory, you can use standard `System.IO` functionality to create directories, save files, and access files.

Other than the above code, much of our file interaction logic is the exact same code for WinMo and WinForms.